# FileField not working in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, filefield

I am trying to create FileField in my forms and without saving file locally, add the file(as an attachment) to email and send it. Email part of code works fine, but when i add FileField it shows me error "'str' object has no attribute 'get'" and i am struggling to figure out what is the problem.

view:

```
def print(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrintForm(data=request.POST, request = request)
        #print(request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')
            supervisor = form.cleaned_data['supervisor']
            template = get_template('threeD/email/contact_template_for_printing.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'supervisor': supervisor,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)
            subject = "New message"

            try:
                email = EmailMessage(
                    subject,
                    content,
                    contact_email,
                    [supervisor],
                    headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
                )
                if request.FILES:
                    #uploaded_file = request.POST.get('file')

                    uploaded_file = request.FILES['stl_file']  # file is the name value which you have provided in form for file field
                    email.attach('uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file.read(), uploaded_file.content_type')
                email.send()
            except:
                return "Attachment error"

            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message.")
            return redirect('/index/print/')

    else:
        form = PrintForm(request=request)

    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['printers'] = Printer.objects.all()
    context_dict['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'threeD/print.html', context_dict)
```

form:

```
class PrintForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    supervisor = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(str(sup.email), str(sup.name)) for sup in Supervisors.objects.all()]
    )
    stl_file = forms.FileField(required=False)
    stl_file.help_text = "Upload your file as .STL format. If you have more than one file, " \
                     "make a .zip and upload them all at once"
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(PrintForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['contact_name'].label = "Your name:"
        self.fields['stl_file'].label = "Choose your design file:"
```

here is HTML code snippet, where i call for the form:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% load bootstrap %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}          
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
        Send a message
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/index/print/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.4.3

Installed Applications:
['admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.menu',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'threeD.apps.ThreedConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrapform',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook']

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

And that's the error i'm getting:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  235.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.4.egg\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  31.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /index/print/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

After removing try-except case from views, i m getting following traceback:
Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\Python\Facility\threeD\views.py" in print
  145.                 email.attach('uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file.read(), uploaded_file.content_type')

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.4.egg\django\core\mail\message.py" in attach
  307.             assert content is not None

Exception Type: AssertionError at /index/print/
Exception Value:
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the clickjacking middleware is blowing up because the response its reading is a string when it should be something else.

Looking at your code this line might be the culprit `return "Attachment error"`

try changing it to

`return HttpResponse('Attachment error')`

you can import HttpResponse like this `from django.http import HttpResponse`

Comment: Thank you for your message, davidejones. I have tried changing the code to make return HttpResponse('Attachment error'), and when i submit my form, it apparently is getting caught in my try-except and returns me blank screen with the text "Attachment error"

Comment: Great so that fixed the immediate error you were having now you can move on to fixing why it's getting to the try catch. You should log/output the error in the catch or remove the try catch completely so you can see the error.

Comment: Well, that's a good point. Now i'm getting the error: AssertionError at /index/print/ (which is my template, which im calling)
No exception message supplied

Comment: I have updated the question with traceback of my current error. It really looks to me that the way i attach file (from the buffer) is not working right

Comment: After removing ' ' brackets from attach method, it successfully passes that lines, but shows an error on the line email.send() to be: "need more than 1 value to unpack". dang, i m so confused with all that

Comment: Looks like the email attach line is the one not working. Those variables shouldn't all be in quotes, here is the method signature def attach(self, filename=None, content=None, mimetype=None)

Comment: wow, you are right, the problem is with attach line. I have changed it to be: " email.attach("lala", uploaded_file.read())" to test and the email got send with a file attached - that's cool. But i received it as lala.dat (which is randomly guessed and assigned extension, as django documentation says) . But how do i keep the uploaded filename and filetype ? :)

Comment: Can you accept an answer on this question, seen as you have created a follow on question to deal with your new errors.

Comment: davidjones, do you think i should better delete this post, since it doesn't help me to resolve the problem, except getting one step closer to realization where the problem arises ?

Comment: Technically i resolved the issue with `Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` so i think its fine to keep the question it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to populate the model/DB. You should use data from form.

So for the file field you should do

```
uploaded_file = form.cleaned_data['stl_file']
```

Also, don't do, use data from `form.cleaned_data`

```
contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
```

Rather use

```
contact_name = form.cleaned_data.get('contact_name', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rohan. I have tried using uploaded_file = form.cleaned_data['stl_file'], but with no luck. It still blows up and shows me the same error :/ 
I have also tried using contact_name = form.cleaned_data.get('contact_name', '') approach, but it shows me the error: 'dict' object is not callable